# How to obfuscate a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, obfuscation

I am using Ubuntu 10.04. i have created a shell script. After writing the script, the code can be edited when right clicking the file and selecting Gedit. I want to know how to make the script unreadable in Gedit.

Comment: A script _must_ be readable for the interpreter to be able to run it. Are you asking how to re-write your script as a program in a compiled language to deter someone from making modifications to the script? Or... what are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compilers for shell scripts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297318/compilers-for-shell-scripts)

Comment: Obfuscation is something different than missing access (read) permissions. Which one do you mean?

Comment: I don't think this question should be marked as a bad question. IMHO it's good to know how to make a shell script not readable or writable for security reasons. Sometimes filesystem permissions are not enough (I know there are cool features like selinux, btw...), because some people in some work teams may become root too easily... So for me this is a good question.

Comment: In my opinion, if obfuscation is a requirement, then shell (or any other interpreted language) is the wrong tool for the task.

Answer (score 6):

**GEdit** is just another tool that can be used to edit a file, much like "vi" or "nano" is.  Only difference is, I believe it is graphical. Nevertheless, it appears that what the original poster is attempting to do here is to simply make it impossible for others to view certain scripts. If that's true, there are solutions that may be worth investigating.

**SHC:**

SHC is a great tool to use for this purpose. and based on the last post in this thread, it appears the OP has already tried it but, it didn't work on certain systems. If that's the case, heres's the reason why.  The way SHC works is actually pretty straight-forward. When using it to obfuscate a script, you have to re-compile the script for whichever OS you intend to run it on.  What that means is, you cannot run the SHC compiler on a ubuntu box and expect the produced script to work on a Red Hat/CentOS box. It appears the latest version of SHC can be [accessed here](https://github.com/neurobin/shc).

**EnScryption:**

If your main goal is to discourage others from attempting to read your code, you can just paste your script to a site like [this one](http://www.EnScryption.com/kinglazy-shieldx-premium-members.php). This site will automatically generate an obfuscated version of your script that should be able to run without issues on most common Unix systems.

If you do not wish to paste your code to the above site or use SHC for whatever reason, then, there's yet another solution.  Use openssl!

**OpenSSL:**

If your scripts are really that sensitive, then Openssl(or a similar tool) is probably the best option for you. Why? Because the openssl tool in particular is present on most Unix systems...i.e. Ubuntu, CentOS, Red Hat, Macs, AIX.  It comes as part of the default installation.  If you decide to go this route, note, you will need to write your script in such a way that before it runs, the user has to provide a password.

**Encrypting your script with OpenSSL:**

```
cat yourscript.sh | openssl aes-128-cbc -a -salt -k (specify-a-password-here) > yourscript.enc.sh

(OR)

openssl aes-128-cbc -a -salt -in yourscript.sh -k (specify-a-password-here) > yourscript.enc.sh

(OR)

openssl aes-128-cbc -a -salt -in yourscript.sh -out yourscript.enc.sh -k (specify-a-password-here)
```

**Decrypting your script with OpenSSL:**

```
cat yourscript.enc.sh | openssl aes-128-cbc -a -d -salt -k (specify-a-password-here) > yourscript.dec.sh

(OR)

openssl aes-128-cbc -a -d -salt -in yourscript.sh -k (specify-a-password-here) > yourscript.dec.sh

(OR)

openssl aes-128-cbc -a -d -salt -in yourscript.sh -out yourscript.enc.sh -k (specify-a-password-here)
```

A quick thing to note about the openssl encryption mechanism '**aes-128-cbc**':

There are probably more secure mechanisms out there.  But there is a good chance some of the systems you wish to run your encrypted scripts on wont have those mechanisms, thereby making it impossible to run your script.  So keep that in mind if you decide to change it.

Answer (score 4):

Obfuscation (which is what most people mean when they say they want a "binary" shell script) is a Bad Idea(TM) - Been there, done that. It doesn't provide any security against a determined programmer (they'd just trace the script to figure out what it's doing), and it makes it really, really hard to debug (which, possibly unless you're [GreyCat](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/GreyCat), you *will* need to do. A lot.).

Answer (score 3):

You are probably looking for something like shc.
From the man page:

shc creates a stripped  binary  executable  version  of  the
     script specified with -f on the command line.

http://freecode.com/projects/shc

Disclaimer: I have not tested shc nor do I know how well/if it works

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is not readily possible. Scripts are interpreted, not compiled, that's why you see text in there.

For an script to be executed, the effective user must have read access to it. An alternative to giving execution permission or using shc (as KillerX has nicely proposed), without letting the user look at the contests of the script, would be to use **sudo**. You would edit the `sudoers` file like this (remember to use `visudo` to edit this file!):

```
username ALL=(ALL) /path/to/your_script.sh
```

Now the script would be executable by "username" but he wouldn't be able to read its contents. Of course, you need to remove all permissions to "username" from this file...

Comment: what is need is after creating the script i was converted execute permission. if i will give this script to some other person that person must not able to open this script, they can only run this script.

Comment: Then you should try shc. I can't figure out other solution beyond using a non-interpreted language.

Comment: i was download the shc 3.8.7 and installed successfully, then the script test.sh was converted to test.sh.x format.Then through terminal i was ran ./test.sh.x. It was run my system. BUT the same test.sh.x was copied and paste it into another system and installed shc. then i ran ./test.sh.x it was not run. what to do.