# C++ running command in linux terminal I dont get it

Tags: c++, linux, bash, terminal, command

I'm teaching myself C++ let's get that on the table. I learn best by choosing what I want to program and just doing it, the step by step hello world and so on tuts are to slow for me so that aside now.

I am trying to figure out how to run a string I got through `getline` (cin,str) in terminal (Kubuntu). I read through `system()` that sounded like a bad option, `fork()` I dont get fully, and `exec()` either. Maybe I'm thinking of this wrong.

Basically I would like to move a bash script I wrote and make it a program. I'm pretty sure it's not a small task but I'm doing this for fun. Any help is welcome. No code pasted because it's so basic it might as well not exist.

Comment: Could you try describe what exactly you are doing? You said string - afterwards you say bashscript ? What have you done, what have you entered and what did you expect to happen/ wanted to happen?

Comment: Did you read http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/ ? Did you read some good book on C++ programming? Did you consider learning an easier-to-learn but powerful language like Ocaml (http://caml.inria.fr & http://ocaml.org/ ...)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `system()` or `fork()` or `exec()`. These are all system calls for spawning processes from another process.

Instead, you simply need a main() method, and then read the command-line args and/or stdin. e.g. from [here](http://wwwx.cs.unc.edu/~sparkst/howto/cpp_main.php)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main( int argc, const char* argv[] )
{
    printf( "\nHello World\n\n" );
}
```

Don't forget that your program will likely not compile to anywhere on your path, and you should probably invoke it specifying the appropriate directory e.g.

```
$ ./myprogram
```

Comment: Okay, well im just testing the best way to take user input. Then i want to use that in my terminal.(from terminal view) Example: Hello user!! Name your file to find :  (user enters file name) foo.sh   now i can take the foo.sh they entered and add it to a command waiting for it. Like find mystring. 
This is just a example and a basic usage im looking for. The bash script i will be basicly rewriting in C++ takes user input at diff times so ill need to beable to use command like that.

Comment: LOL down voted? I wonder if its because my grammar and spelling is horrible.

Comment: d4rkh4nd@: although that might seem like a reasonable exercise in writing C++, it isn't really.  Shells like Bash have a fundamentally different role to C++, shells are for running other programs.  You can do that in C++, but that is not its primary role, you will be missing the strengths of C++ if you look at it as a replacement for a shell.  Consider why you are learning C++ if you can do everying in Bash.

Comment: it's a rubbish question, but this doesn't answer it.

Comment: cdarke@: my goal here is just to learn and you comment is actualy very helpfull i never thought about it like that. I belived c/c++ was the core for most programs (popular opinion) so i would like to learn by wrighting a simple one based off a bash i wrote.

Comment: So i cant post a new question so ill just continue here till i can. How do i call the value of kdialog --password? I would like to avoid entering my sudo password several times in a row.
Im sure someone will say sudo in a script bad idea. Kool not a answer to the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> > Basically I would like to move a bash script I wrote and make it a program

You can use [shc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297318/compilers-for-shell-scripts) to convert your script into a program.