# Read permission needed in order to execute a file?

Tags: c, linux, shell, executable, file-permissions

I'm trying to make a simple c-shell like program on C (for Linux) that will execute scripts.

I need to read a script file in order to execute it, but how can I read it if it has only execute permission, and no read permission?

Comment: you can't, you need to give the file read permissions as well.

Comment: So how bash can execute files without read permission&

Comment: If you're writing in C, you should be able to call `system(...)` or `execlp(...)`, etc, to execute an executable program (whether it's script, binary, or whatever). You don't "read" it first to execute it.

Comment: @Простопрограммист _So how bash can execute files without read permission_ ... It can't. `chmod 400` == Permission denied; `chmod 100` == Permission denied; `chmod 500` == executes script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757357/i-want-a-shell-script-to-be-executable-but-not-readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need `read` permissions to execute script.

However, I want to mention one possibility for `another_user` to run script without having `r` permission on the file.

You can allow ***somebody*** to execute `somescript` with `sudo` as ***another_user*** that have an `r+x` access to file.
However, you should have an access to `/etc/sudoers` (i.e., to be `root`, or ask superuser to add the record from below to `etc/sudoers`)

```
# Run script as the user 'another_user' without asking for password
somebody ALL = (another_user) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/somescript
```

Solution found at
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/77538 and
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21309969/1566267

Answer (score 6):

In short,

- A binary file you can execute with only execute permissions.
- A script is a text file, so you need read permissions.

So, you would need to play some games with group ownership, sudo, or similar.

Comment: This is the best answer!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need read permission in order to execute a file.
In fact, if you have read permission, but not execute permission, you can't execute the file.
The execute permission allows you to ask the system to execute the script file.

Try with:

```
system("script.sh");
```

in order to execute a script (in the example script.sh).

You could also use:

```
execve("script.sh");
```

That would run the script replacing your script with the one in the specified script keeping the same pid as your script (as shown [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html))

Comment: You certainly can execute it if you can read it, just not directly.

Comment: unfortunately i can't use system() ,
I'm using execve to execute programs, but script is only text file

Comment: @Deduplicator Well, you should copy the content to another file on which you have execute permissions... but that's another story!

Comment: @clami219: Or go directly to the user-space dynamic loader, or call the interpreter, ...

Comment: @Deduplicator Ok, but that's not the topic here... What I meant here is that read permission is not needed in order to execute a script (in the classical sense of the term, using a system call).

Comment: file have execute permission, but doesn't have read permission, but my program must read it to execute commands

Comment: script must be executed by my program, not by system

Comment: @Просто программист Maybe what I added regarding execve may help

Answer (score 0):

The classic way of doing this is to make the wrapper C application setuid root.  Root can read everything, regardless of permissions.  That comes with a whole bunch of warnings though.  Make sure that you're not closing a small security hole by opening a much larger one.